# Where does Eclipse deploy web applications using WTP?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, eclipse-wtp

I have a web application (WAR file). When I deploy it through Eclipse 3.5 using the WTP tools, I am able to start the Tomcat server from within Eclipse and view all the pages of the application. However I don't see my WAR file inside the *webapps* folder of Tomcat home directory (or for that matter its exploded format). I was under the impression that Tomcat reads all web applications under its *webapps* folder. How does Tomcat read my application in this case? I am using Tomcat 5.5.17 as my application server.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's just all definied in the `context.xml` which Eclipse has given to Tomcat. If you want to configure this behaviour, then doubleclick the Tomcat instance in the servers view and check the *Server locations* section. To achieve what you initially want/expected, you need to select *Use Tomcat installation* and if necessary also specify the *Deploy path*.

Comment: What do you mean by `context.xml which eclipse has given to tomcat`? Where is the context.xml located?

Comment: In my case the server locations section is disabled in eclipse.

Comment: It's specified in *Server path* field of the *Server locations* section. You need to browse furher something like `tmp0\conf\Catalina\localhost` and there you'll find the `context.xml` (which is *actually* named `contextPathAsYouHaveSpecified.xml`).

Comment: It is disabled when the server is already published with modules. **Read** the leading text of the section :)

Comment: ya I found it. But the context.xml contains only 1 line
`<WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>`

What does that mean? I am curious to find out that how come tomcat loads it.

Comment: It's actually not the one you're asking for. The one you found is located in something like `tmp0\conf`, but you need to browse further something like `tmp0\conf\Catalina\localhost`. At any way, the `WatchedResource` setting is just to trigger the auto-deployer. Also see Tomcat docs: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/deployer-howto.html

Comment: I dont have any other folder inside tmp0\conf\.

Comment: Then nothing has been published to Tomcat through Eclipse yet. Or you actually changed the *Server locations*.

Comment: I think application has been published.Because if I change any jsp file, I can see the changes on the UI. Same applies for class changes as well.

Comment: Oh, I already see, I configured my Tomcat to *Publish module contexts to separate XML files*. When it's disabled (as likely in your case) it's definied in `tmp0\conf\server.xml`.

Comment: And I have not changed my Server locations as well.

Comment: Ya I got it. Thanks a lot. You have been very patient and helpful. I will upvote your response as soon as I am able to, as currently SO says that my daily vote limit has reached.

Comment: @BalusC I kept the default settings, when I do Run on Server the following folder structure(all web app folders) is created, jars copied but not class files. How to fix this issue.        workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/myapp/WEB-INF/classes/com/myapp/web

Comment: @BalusC I end up with ClassNotFoundException with the missing class files. I used maven and war is created in 'target' by running 'clean install'. If I deploy the war manually in tomcat it works. But Run on Server fails with the above issue.

Answer (score 52):

I recently have to figure out more detail on this topic to troubleshoot application startup issues so I note it here.

### Where is the application deployed?

It is determined by the server configuration.  Double click on the server in the servers view to look at the server "Overview".   In the "Server Locations" section, there are default value configured:

- Server Path: `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0`
- Deploy Path: `wtpwebapps`

Also the application "module" is defined in the "Modules" tab of the server configuration which specify the application path, document base and the module name.  For example, you deploy your project `myapp` to the path `/MyApp`.

So if your workspace is `/home/me/workspace/myapp`, the path to your application deployment directory is:

```
/home/me/workspace/myapp/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/myapp.
```

### What application files are deployed?

The contents of deployment is determined by "Deployment Assembly" in the project properties.  Each entry in the assembly defines what files are deployed to what path. Example:

- `/src/main/java -> WEB-INF/classes`
- `/src/main/resources -> WEB-INF/classes`
- `/src/main/webapp -> /`
- `Maven Dependencies -> WEB-INF/lib`

So if you have the file `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml` in your source tree, it will be deployed to:

```
/home/me/workspace/myapp/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/myapp/WEB-INF/web.xml
```

Comment: +1. Very nice and to the point answer. Special thanks for explaining what is the purpose of the "Deployment Assembly" option.