# eclipse default build and ant build

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

Cntrl+B( or clean-> build) will build complete java project under eclipse environment. Is this build uses project which is configured default build or it builds based on the eclipse plugin?

one of the java application I have seen is eclipse build will build complete project and depoy in the tomcat directory. How this is happening?

Comment: Well, eclipse is able to package its own build and deploy it in a server. Which build is used depends on the project setup, e.g. a Maven project would normally be built using the Maven plugin in Eclipse whereas an Ant project is normally built using the provided ant build scripts (configurable, e.g. which target to use etc.).

Comment: in my eclipse I have different projects which is having its own build.xml. but I don't think eclipse uses this build to build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have seen the deployment feature with an Eclipse configured with [WTP (Web Tools Platform)](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/).
WTP is featured in the Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers and Eclipse IDE for JavaScript Web Developers, and contributes to many of the other Indigo packages.

WTP is able to deploy an app in a Tomcat (or in a [local Tomcat within Eclipse itself](http://www.vogella.de/blog/2009/04/08/eclipse-wtp-deployment-location-of-the-local-tomcat/)).
See also "[How does eclipse deploy web applications using WTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119351/how-does-eclipse-deploy-web-applications-using-wtp)"

You can see an example a a build and deployment in "[HowToSetupEclipseWtp](http://wiki.apache.org/tapestry/HowToSetupEclipseWtp)".