# Web app does not start inside eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat7

I have created a webapp based on this example:

http://code4reference.com/2012/09/hello-world-web-application/

I have converted it into a dynamic web project using eclipse 4.2. The structure is:

```
MyProject
 -> src
 -> webapp
    -> WEB-INF
      -> appContext
         -> beans.xml
         -> mappings.xml
      -> web.xml
```

I have a local installation of tomcat 7 that I specify when setting up the server inside eclipse. When I run the server (with the above web app) I get:

```
14-11-2012 14:12:08 org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
...
14-11-2012 14:12:09 org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:MyProject' did not find a matching property.
14-11-2012 14:12:09 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
14-11-2012 14:12:09 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
14-11-2012 14:12:09 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 563 ms
14-11-2012 14:12:09 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
14-11-2012 14:12:09 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.32
14-11-2012 14:12:09 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
14-11-2012 14:12:09 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
14-11-2012 14:12:09 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 680 ms
```

and then nothing happens. I have tried to access this url:

```
http://localhost:8080/HelloWorld/hi
```

but get HTTP Status 404 - /HelloWorld/hi. Are there any logs anywhere that might point me to a direction where it goes wrong?

EDIT: I have also tried to follow this guide:

http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/tutorials/BuildJ2EEWebApp/BuildJ2EEWebApp.html

but gives the same result - nothing happens. I have tried to put a breakpoint in the line:

```
String userAgent =  req.getHeader("user-agent");
```

in:

```
public class SnoopServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String userAgent =  req.getHeader("user-agent");
```

but it never gets to that line. If I right-click the project (MyWebApp) inside eclipse and choose "Run as -> run on server" a browser is opened inside eclipse:

[image]

The project is added to the server:

[image]

and run inside eclipse:

[image]

this is the content of com.sample.SnoopServlet:

```
package com.sample;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class SnoopServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String userAgent =  req.getHeader("user-agent");
        String clientBrowser =  "Not known!";   
        if( userAgent != null)
            clientBrowser = userAgent;
        req.setAttribute("client.browser",clientBrowser );
        req.getRequestDispatcher("/showBrowser.jsp").forward(req,resp);
    }
}
```

And this is the content of web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
    version="2.4">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Snoop Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sample.SnoopServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Snoop Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/snoop/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <!-- Don't remove the below section -->
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file></welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: There are log files in the log directory of your tomcat.

Comment: C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.32\logs is empty

Comment: Is your `.war` file deployed in `C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.32\webapps`? Maybe you have configured tomcat in eclipse to use different locations.

Comment: No I currently don't build a war file. I would like to run it inside eclipse only. Of course I still specify the path to the local tomcat installation when going through the servers wizard in eclipse.

Comment: Did your add your project to server?

Comment: Your web app doesn't appear to be deployed on your server at all. That's why your break point isn't getting hit. You must either start the server from within eclipse as outlined in my tutorial  below, or export your web app to a war and deploy it to your server.

Comment: Yes its deployed on the server and I run it inside eclipse - see above screenshot.

Comment: No, it isn't. The server would give some output regarding your webapp if it were starting it. You can verify using your tomcat server's admin page.

Comment: Hm http://localhost:8080/ just gives: HTTP Status 404 - /

Comment: Yes this is because you are using internal eclipse tomcat dev server, not default tomcat installation with nice home page and admin tools. That's why i like better to export a .war file.

Comment: I think the problem might be with your web.xml deployment descriptor. Are you certain that it is correct? I am also not sure if your project has a sun-jaxws.xml, but if it does you need to verify it too.

Comment: The web.xml is from the tutorial (see above): http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/tutorials/BuildJ2EEWebApp/BuildJ2EEWebApp.html

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19535/discussion-between-u123-and-eric-b)

Answer (score 1):

1. Download the Tomcat Source, and build it.
   a. Follow the instructions in BUILDING.txt. It's quick and easy if you already have a JDK and Ant, which you probably do.
   b. Move the /output/build directory somewhere and rename it, eg. /home/me/apache-tomcat-7.0.29
2. In Eclipse, Window->Show View->Servers
3. Right Click in Servers->New->Server
4. Apache->Tomcat v7.0 Server
   a. Server's host name: localhost
   b. Server name: whatever you like (Tomcat 7)
   c. Server runtime environment: Apache Tomcat v7.0
   d. Finish
5. OPTIONAL) Double click your new server
   a. Edit your desired ports
6. Now in Eclipse, Right Click->New->Dynamic Web Project
   a. Name your project: NO SPACES OR IT WILL NOT WORK (My_Tomcat_Project)
   b. Target Runtime: Apache Tomcat v7.0
   c. Web Module: Web module 3.0
   d. Configuration: Default Configuration for Apache Tomcat v7.0
   e. Finish
   f. Write your webapp
7. Save the project.
8. Deploy it to the Tomcat Server (Drag and Drop from Project Explorer to Servers view)
9. Start the server
10. You're Done!
    a) Navigate to `localhost:{port}/{Project_Name}/{url_pattern}` to see a web page describing your new web service.
    b) eg. `http://localhost:8080/My_Tomcat_Project/hello`
    c) From here you can access the generated WSDL file.

Comment: Yes its the last approach I am going for - I have installed the necessary tomcat connectors/adapters in eclipse and done what you suggested above.

Comment: are you starting the server with eclipse or with a terminal? You must start it with eclipse.

Comment: I am running on windows7 64bit and I run it inside eclipse and have followed the steps above (besides build tomcat myself I have downloaded the binary version).

Comment: Do you start it in eclipse from the servers view, or do you use Sysdeo Tomcat Launcher Plugin with the picture of the cat that starts the server externally?

Comment: I start it from the servers view inside eclipse. I don't have any buttons with a cat.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue recently, and one thing help me is to understanding where is application files deployed to and from where.  I put together my finding [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119351/how-does-eclipse-deploy-web-applications-using-wtp/14105487#14105487).

In my particular case, I found that I only had compiled class files being deployed, but none of my WEB-INF/* files were deployed, thus no web.xml file to start the application.  After validating all the tomcat server configuration and deployment assembly configuration are correct, it occurred to me to do: right click on the server -> "Clean".   This will complete clean the deployment directory and re-publish.

My workspace was somehow stuck in a state that "publish" was not publishing everything and needed to clean it up.  Note that "Clean"ing the project does not clean the deployment directory and it didn't get me out of my bad state. Also note that "Clean Tomcat Work Directory" cleans ./work directory and does not clean the application directory either.