# maven goals, compiling and deploying to a server

Tags: eclipse, maven, tomcat, compilation

I'm using eclipse to manage a maven project.

In the pom of this project I have a special plugin, which create a file during the generate-ressources phase :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.acceleo</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>acceleo-compile</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I have linked this plugin goal to eclipse lifecycle to execute it during eclipse compilation :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
            <pluginExecutions>
                <pluginExecution>
                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                        <groupId>org.eclipse.acceleo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven</artifactId>
                        <versionRange>[3.2.1,)</versionRange>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>acceleo-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                    <action>
                        <execute />
                    </action>
                </pluginExecution>
            </pluginExecutions>
        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

When I do a clean project with eclipse, the project compile again and the file is well generated during the eclipse compilation (I can find it in the target directory).

Now, I want to deploy my webapp on a tomcat server. I create a tomcat server using the server view of eclipse and I drag and drop the project into this server to synchronize and publish it.

The project is well deployed and I can launch the server and test my app.

BUT, the file which needs to be generated by the maven plugin is not copied during the publish operation...

So my question is : why the file generated by a maven plugin is well generated during the eclipse compilation but is not deployed on the server during the publish/synchronize operation of the automatic server management by eclipse ?

Comment: I assume you have added the plugin only in the pluginManagement area.

Comment: no, It is defined in build/plugins

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in your question, cause you configured the plugin to run only during the eclipse Life cylce, but you've missed to add the exection to your build life cycle.

Comment: I don't understand, what do you mean add the execution to the build life cycle ? I was thinking the execution (phase generate-resources) tag was here for that.

Comment: This is only valid for Eclipse but not for Maven.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the publishing of your webapp is done by eclipse [wtp](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/common/) tools.

To configure this (what gets deployed to the server) check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2119351/332248) and the according answers.

In short: I think you need to configure that the generated file (from your target dir) is also copied when wtp deploys your app.

Comment: Hum, the link is interesting, because it's saying that it uses the deployment descriptor and not the target directory to deploy files. And so, the file is ignored during the tranfer...