# How tomcat is running my project in Eclipse?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat

I know how to configure tomcat to run my Dynamic web project created in eclipse. 
Can any body please explain me the step by step process which tomcat does to run my web project?

Comment: Go to console and see the steps....

Comment: I can see like;
Jul 31, 2013 8:32:17 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
INFO: Reloading Context with name [/TestApp] has started
Jul 31, 2013 8:32:18 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
INFO: Reloading Context with name [/TestApp] is completed

Comment: Is tomcat creating any WAR file of running project?

Answer (score 2):

I could see a detail clarification regarding this in following links;

[Where does Eclipse deploy web applications using WTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119351/how-does-eclipse-deploy-web-applications-using-wtp)

http://oreilly.com/pub/a/java/archive/tomcat.html?page=1

http://www.mulesoft.com/tomcat-deploy