# Web Deployment Assembly not used by Tomcat7

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, ubuntu

My understanding is when running tomcat inside of eclipse, during publishing... eclipse will copy files based on the settings in Web Deployment Assembly to tomcat directory. I added my app to Tomcat 7 thru Server --> "Add or Remove...", when I start tomcat, I don't see any files been copied to /usr/share/tomcat7/wtpwebapps/myapp folder. BTW, I have all the folder structure (folders) under tomcat directory, but missing all the files (like .class, .properties, .xml and ...). This is the error I am getting when start tomcat. BTW, the directory show in the pic is the directory under tomcat. I thought the publishing process copies files from eclipse to tomcat dir? It looks like it's trying to copy files from tomcat dir to somewhere else. What am I missing? My Server path and Deploy path are all correct.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where does Eclipse deploy web applications using WTP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119351/where-does-eclipse-deploy-web-applications-using-wtp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a permission thing. Also I recommend install tomcat manually instead of running apt-get.
Either https://askubuntu.com/questions/17223/permissions-problem-when-copying-files-to-usr-share-tomcat6 or http://www.frattv.com/tomcat-can-t-start-from-ide-eclipse-luna-wtp-intellij-idea-in-ubuntu/ will work.